# php edit form, get dropdown to pull value for that record

Tags: php

I have 2 forms, one where I enter records and one where I edit records.

On the form that I add records, I have a drop down which queries another table in my database for the values.

When I click on the "edit" record form to edit this data, I am unable to get the value that has already been entered to be pre-selected in the dropdown.

```
 <select name="aankomstluchthaven">
    <option name="aankomstluchthaven" value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
  $list=mysql_query("select luchthavenID, luchthavencode from tbl_luchthaven 
  order by luchthavencode ASC");
 while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
?>
<option value="<?echo $row_list['luchthavenID']; ?>"> <?echo    
  $row_list['luchthavencode']; ?> </option>
    <?
         }
         ?>
</select>
```

the field that is being updated is 'aankomstluchthaven'. So the value from my table where the form data is stored (tbl_vluchtgegevens) should be populated. 
Where tbl_luchthaven.luchthavenID = tbl_vluchtgegevens.aankomstluchthaven

I tried putting  in the option value, but that is not what I"m looking for.

Edit to include example php page with dropdown (note, I have changed from aankomstluchthaven in the example above to vertrekluchthaven in the example below. same thing applies.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>bijwerk vluchtgegevens Form</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <?    include "datalogin.php";//database connection
  $order = "SELECT * 
            FROM tbl_vluchtgegevens 
            WHERE gegevenID='$id'";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 ?>
 <table border=1>
<tr>
<td width="547" align=center>bijwerk vluchtgegevens: <br>
gegevenID = <? echo "$row[gegevenID]"?></td>
<td width="547" align=center>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <table>

  <form method="post" action="bijwerkvlucht_post.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo "$row[gegevenID]"?>">
    <tr>
      <td width="208">Vertrekluchthaven </td>
      <td width="325">
        <select name="vertrekluchthaven">
    <option name="vertrekluchthaven" value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
  $list=mysql_query("select luchthavenID, luchthavencode from tbl_luchthaven order by luchthavencode ASC");
 while($row_list=mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
  ?>
    <option value="<?echo $row_list['luchthavenID']; ?>"> <?echo 
 $row_list['luchthavencode']; ?> </option>
    <?
         }
         ?>
  </select> 
  </td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td align="right">
        <input type="submit" 
      name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">          </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  </table>    </td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <?php
 // close connection 
 mysql_close();
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting the values by id or whatever when you edit the form, you would do something like this:

```
<option value="<?echo $row_list['luchthavenID']; ?>" <? echo ($row['luchthavenID'] == $row_list['luchthavenID'] ? ' selected="selected"' : ''); ?>> <?echo $row_list['luchthavencode']; ?> </option>
```

Each time through the loop you check the value against the values pulled in the query. If they match, you make this option selected.

**UPDATED**
I still don't know what your field is called, but assuming it is `$row['luchthavenID']` I would write it like this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row_list['luchthavenID'].'"'.($row['luchthavenID'] == $row_list['luchthavenID'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$row_list['luchthavencode'].'</option>';
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. I'm wondering if it's how my entire code is setup that's causing the issue. I'm going to edit the above and see if I can't get a simpler example to include all of the code from my php page.

Comment: That would help. I was guessing on how you are getting your values.

Comment: this is done. i have added it in my original message.